# Package and Publish msi installer into Windows 10 App Store [DESKTOP ONLY]?

Tags: windows, windows-10, appstore-approval, windows-store

We have a msi Installer for our project and would like to package and publish it to Windows 10 App Store [Desktop ONLY]. Can you please provide some insight or pointers where I should start looking at? Is this even possible ? Or are there any restrictions potential issues in trying to do the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, there are no option to upload .MSI -Classic Windows Application- package to windows store. Windows store is only applicable for AppX package.

But, once if 'Project Centennial' is available, you can transform your .MSI package to AppX. MS says so.
You can get the detail of 'project centennial' from here.(It seems that the schedule is delayed...)

- [Windows Bridges](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/bridges)
- [Project Centennial: Converting your Classic Windows App (Win32, .Net, COM) to a Universal Windows App for Distribution in the Windows Store](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2015/2-692)

Note - Win8.1 Store had a function 'Desktop Application Listing' - you could upload just a 'link' of the app download site.
But this service was ended with Win10 Release.

[Tomb of desktop application listing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn374787(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your response :-)

Comment: How can we make msi installer for uwp application in windows 10?